# Linux Mint does not ask for password

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Normally, if I try to start a program or execute a command (not in the terminal) that requires su privileges, a window will show up asking for the password.

However, the window stopped showing up, so whenever I try to start a program that requires su privileges (such as GParted) or execute a command like choosing "Open as Root" in a folder, nothings happens. I would have to type something like `sudo gparted` in the terminal in order to start the program properly.

How do I solve this?

The output of `sudo cat /etc/sudoers` is

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: What is the output of `sudo cat /etc/sudoers`?

Comment: @GAD3R added the output in the post.